# Binding to a Property that only have get method

Tags: data-binding, winrt-xaml

I have a question regarding binding in WinRT. 
I have a Viewmodel like this:

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Vehicle> _vehicles = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();
    public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _vehicles; }
        set { _vehicles = value; }
    }
```

and also I have some properties that I get the value from this main list, for example

```
    public int GetType1Vehicles
    {
        get { return Vehicles.Where(x => x.Type == Type1).Count(); }
    }

    public int TotalVehicles
    {
        get { return Vehicles.Count(); }
    }
```

I binded a UI textbox to a "GetType1Vehicles" and another textbot to a "TotalVehicles". The problem is that when I update the Vehicle List, the ListView with all vehicles is correctly updated but the Total and the Type don't. What I doing wrong?
Anybody can help me? Thanks!

UPDATE
I found a workarround, but I'm not sure that is the best approach. Every time that I change some from the list, call manually the methods:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("GetType1Vehicles");
RaisePropertyChanged("TotalVehicles");
```

Is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that you will need to manually call RaisePropertyChanged. Anyway, why do you have a TotalVehicles property when you could just bind to "Vehicles.Count"?

Answer (score 0):

David is right, why this TotalVehicles property ?

With an ObservableCollection, you should not call the Count() method, just use the **Count property**.
The Count method is usefull if you want to count only the items with a specific value, not the size of the collection, that's the job of the property.